# Start Token in LSTM Decoder

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, mencoder

I understand the encoder-decoder model, and how the output of the encoder will be the input of the decoder. Assume here I have decoder model only, I have the decoder initial_state (i.e. decoder_states_inputs are given).

I want to give the "decoder_inputs" to be the start token (for example < start > )... but I don't know how and in what format?!

```
decoder_lstm = LSTM(n_units, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)    
decoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs, initial_state=decoder_states_inputs)
```

Also, must I add the start token to my original sequences? i.e.:

```
 <start> statemnt1
 <start> statemnt2
 ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to add `<start>` and `<end>` symbol really depends on how you implement the rest of the model but in most of the cases the results are the same. For example in the [official tensorflow example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.11/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/nmt_with_attention/nmt_with_attention.ipynb), it adds these symbols to every sentence.

```
def preprocess_sentence(w):
    # other preprocessing

    w = w.rstrip().strip()

    # adding a start and an end token to the sentence
    # so that the model know when to start and stop predicting.
    w = '<start> ' + w + ' <end>'
    return w

# rest of the code
# ... word2idx is a dictionary that map words into unique ids
```

Then, in the tokenization part, `<start>` and `<end>` symbols map to 4 and 5 respectively. But, as you can see in the picture, it only feeds `<start>` in the decoder's input and `<end>` to the decoder's output. It means it our data is similar to:

```
decoder_inp = raw_decoder_input[:, 0:-1]
decoder_out = raw_decoder_input[:, 1:]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I understood the first part of your answer, but what do you mean by raw_decoder_input, is it in my case initial_state=decoder_states_inputs??

Comment: @noor No, it is tokenized sequence's that you feed into the network. Decoder output is one token ahead of Deocder input.